# How to compress ObjectID to make it shorter

Tags: javascript

I use `ObjectId` as `url` search params. My goal is to store an array of values.

How I can compress value as `5cbd048be6161e6e40150ec9` to make it more URL friendly?

This value is `mongodb` `_id`.

Comment: What is that? Where does it come from? Does it have to be intact on the other end?